# Best practices to avoid jquery scope / init / issues / conflicts?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a hard time learning the correct way to build out a misc. javascript / jquery file. I tend to place functions and vars next to each other as I go, but I invariably run into issues as the file gets big.

I move a block up or down and it breaks something else. I place a simple `alert('hello');` at the end of the doc ready block, and it won't work, but it works at the top. This file I tried putting all the vars at the top, outside the doc ready and all the functions outside the doc ready at the bottom.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/fmd7c8kw/)

```
var mobileMenuWrapper = $('div.mobile-menu-wrapper');
var mobileMenuToggler = $('.mobile-nav-toggle');
var mobileMailToggler = $('#mobileMailToggle');
var currentPage = $('main').attr('id');
var btnSlideLeft = $('.btn-slide-left');
var btnScrollDown = $('.btn-page-scroll');
var itemBox = $('.item-box');
var btnSquare = $('.btn-square');
var pageNavItem = $('.page-nav li');
var serviceBtn = $('.service-box .icon-loader');
var slideNum, serviceId;
var page = new fullpage(`#${currentPage}`, {
  autoScrolling: true,
  continuousHorizontal: false,
  controlArrows: false,
  dragAndMove: false,
  fixedElements: '.topbar',
  loopHorizontal: false,
  responsiveSlides: false,
  scrollingSpeed: 500,
  touchSensitivity: 5,
  verticalCentered: false,
  normalScrollElements: '#intro, #services',
  onLeave: function (index, nextIndex, direction) {
  },

  onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {
  },
  afterRender: function () {
  },
  afterResize: function () {
  },
  afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
  },
  afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
    if (index === 2 && currentPage === 'venueDetail' || index === 2 && currentPage === 'experienceDetail') {
      getSliderCount();
      $('.slide-counter').fadeIn();
    }
  },
  afterResponsive: function (isResponsive) {
  }
});
var capacitySlider = $('#venueCapacity').slider({
  range: true,
  stop: 100,
  handle: 'custom',
});
var squareFootageSlider = $('#squareFootage').slider({
  range: true,
  step: 500,
  handle: 'custom',
});
// document ready
$(function () {
   $('.fade-in').show();
  $('.use-current-location').click(function () {
    $('.rep-results').fadeIn();
  });
  $('.toggle-experience').click(function () {
    $('.map-view').toggle();
    $('.grid-view').toggle();
  });

  $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      return $('#popover-content-' + id).html();
    },
    title: function () {
      var title = $(this).attr('data-popover-content');
      return $(title).children('.popover-heading').html();
    }
  });

  $(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'Escape') {
      $('.popover').removeClass('show');
    }
  });

  serviceBtn.click(function () {
    serviceId = $(this).prop('id');
    slideNum = serviceId.substr(serviceId.length - 1) - 1;
    console.log(slideNum);
    page.moveTo(2, slideNum);
  });

  btnSlideLeft.click(function () {
    page.moveSlideLeft();
    getSliderCount();
  });
  var btnSlideRight = $('.btn-slide-right');
  btnSlideRight.click(function () {
    page.moveSlideRight();
    getSliderCount();
  });

  $('#desktopMailToggle').click(function () {
    $('aside.sidebar').toggleClass('open');
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });

  mobileMenuToggler.click(function () {
    mobileMenuWrapper.toggleClass('menu-open');
    if (mobileMenuWrapper.hasClass('contact-form-showing')) {
      mobileMenuWrapper.removeClass('contact-form-showing');
      $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    }
  });

  mobileMailToggler.click(function () {
    mobileMenuWrapper.toggleClass('contact-form-showing');
    if (mobileMenuWrapper.hasClass('contact-form-showing')) {
      $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    } else {
      $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
    }
  });

  pageNavItem.click(function () {
    var section = $(this).index() + 1;
    page.moveTo(section);
  });

  btnScrollDown.click(function () {
    page.moveSectionDown();
  });

  btnSquare.click(function () {
    $('.btn-square').removeClass('loading');
    $(this).addClass('loading');
    $('.item-box').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('.item-box').toggleClass('selected');
  });

  itemBox.click(function () {
    $('.item-box').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

  capacitySlider.on('slide', function () {
    getCapacityValue();
  });

  squareFootageSlider.on('slide', function () {
    getSquareFootageValue();
  });

  getCapacityValue();
  getSquareFootageValue();

  $('#resetFilters').click(function () {
    capacitySlider.slider('refresh');
    squareFootageSlider.slider('refresh');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    getCapacityValue();
    getSquareFootageValue();
  });

  $('.grid-map-toggle').click(function () {
    $('.map-view').toggle();
    $('.grid-view').toggle();

    venueResults.recalculate();
  });
  $(window).resize(function () {
    autoHeightMobile();
  });
  autoHeightMobile();

});

// functions

function autoHeightMobile() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth < 768) {
    $('section.section').addClass('fp-auto-height');
  } else {
    $('section.section').removeClass('fp-auto-height');
  }
}

function getSliderCount() {
  var currentSlide;
  var slideCount;
  var total = $('.slide').length;
  var activeSlide = page.getActiveSlide();
  var index = activeSlide.index + 1;
  if (index && index < 10) {
    currentSlide = `0${index}`;
  } else {
    currentSlide = index;
  }
  if (total && total < 10) {
    slideCount = `0${total}`;
  } else {
    slideCount = total;
  }
  $('.slide-index').text(currentSlide);
  $('.slide-total').text(slideCount);
}

function getSquareFootageValue() {
  var squareFootageVal = squareFootageSlider.slider('getValue');
  if ((squareFootageVal[0] + 100) >= squareFootageVal[1]) {
  }
  $('.sf-low').text(squareFootageVal[0]);
  $('.sf-high').text(squareFootageVal[1]);
}

function getCapacityValue() {
  var capacityVal = capacitySlider.slider('getValue');
  if ((capacityVal[0] + 250) >= capacityVal[1]) {
  }
  $('.cap-low').text(capacityVal[0]);
  $('.cap-high').text(capacityVal[1]);
}
```

Comment: wrap everhthing `in $(document).ready(function(){  })`

Comment: This is quite vague. Please provide a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The snippet you provided does not run. Specify what exactly is the problem you bump into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see most of the part of your code is interacting with DOM. So if you remove your all you vars out of the document.ready it will be undefined as html elements are not ready yet. That means jQuery will not be able to find 'div.mobile-menu-wrapper' and it will break. Well moving all the variables at top is good practice, you have taken already one step towards the best practices. So as suggested in comment you have to move everything into `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

```
$(function () {
    var mobileMenuWrapper = $('div.mobile-menu-wrapper');
    var mobileMenuToggler = $('.mobile-nav-toggle');
    var mobileMailToggler = $('#mobileMailToggle');
    var currentPage = $('main').attr('id');
    var btnSlideLeft = $('.btn-slide-left');
    var btnScrollDown = $('.btn-page-scroll');
    var itemBox = $('.item-box');
    var btnSquare = $('.btn-square');
    var pageNavItem = $('.page-nav li');
    var serviceBtn = $('.service-box .icon-loader');
    var slideNum, serviceId;
    var page = new fullpage(`#${currentPage}`, {
        autoScrolling: true,
        continuousHorizontal: false,
        controlArrows: false,
        dragAndMove: false,
        fixedElements: '.topbar',
        loopHorizontal: false,
        responsiveSlides: false,
        scrollingSpeed: 500,
        touchSensitivity: 5,
        verticalCentered: false,
        normalScrollElements: '#intro, #services',
        onLeave: function (index, nextIndex, direction) {
        },

        onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {
        },
        afterRender: function () {
        },
        afterResize: function () {
        },
        afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
        },
        afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
            if (index === 2 && currentPage === 'venueDetail' || index === 2 && currentPage === 'experienceDetail') {
                getSliderCount();
                $('.slide-counter').fadeIn();
            }
        },
        afterResponsive: function (isResponsive) {
        }
    });
    var capacitySlider = $('#venueCapacity').slider({
        range: true,
        stop: 100,
        handle: 'custom',
    });
    var squareFootageSlider = $('#squareFootage').slider({
        range: true,
        step: 500,
        handle: 'custom',
    });
    // document ready

        $('.fade-in').show();
        $('.use-current-location').click(function () {
            $('.rep-results').fadeIn();
        });
        $('.toggle-experience').click(function () {
            $('.map-view').toggle();
            $('.grid-view').toggle();
        });

        $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                return $('#popover-content-' + id).html();
            },
            title: function () {
                var title = $(this).attr('data-popover-content');
                return $(title).children('.popover-heading').html();
            }
        });

        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.key === 'Escape') {
                $('.popover').removeClass('show');
            }
        });

        serviceBtn.click(function () {
            serviceId = $(this).prop('id');
            slideNum = serviceId.substr(serviceId.length - 1) - 1;
            console.log(slideNum);
            page.moveTo(2, slideNum);
        });

        btnSlideLeft.click(function () {
            page.moveSlideLeft();
            getSliderCount();
        });
        var btnSlideRight = $('.btn-slide-right');
        btnSlideRight.click(function () {
            page.moveSlideRight();
            getSliderCount();
        });

        $('#desktopMailToggle').click(function () {
            $('aside.sidebar').toggleClass('open');
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
        });

        mobileMenuToggler.click(function () {
            mobileMenuWrapper.toggleClass('menu-open');
            if (mobileMenuWrapper.hasClass('contact-form-showing')) {
                mobileMenuWrapper.removeClass('contact-form-showing');
                $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
            }
        });

        mobileMailToggler.click(function () {
            mobileMenuWrapper.toggleClass('contact-form-showing');
            if (mobileMenuWrapper.hasClass('contact-form-showing')) {
                $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            } else {
                $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
            }
        });

        pageNavItem.click(function () {
            var section = $(this).index() + 1;
            page.moveTo(section);
        });

        btnScrollDown.click(function () {
            page.moveSectionDown();
        });

        btnSquare.click(function () {
            $('.btn-square').removeClass('loading');
            $(this).addClass('loading');
            $('.item-box').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).closest('.item-box').toggleClass('selected');
        });

        itemBox.click(function () {
            $('.item-box').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });

        capacitySlider.on('slide', function () {
            getCapacityValue();
        });

        squareFootageSlider.on('slide', function () {
            getSquareFootageValue();
        });

        getCapacityValue();
        getSquareFootageValue();

        $('#resetFilters').click(function () {
            capacitySlider.slider('refresh');
            squareFootageSlider.slider('refresh');
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
            getCapacityValue();
            getSquareFootageValue();
        });

        $('.grid-map-toggle').click(function () {
            $('.map-view').toggle();
            $('.grid-view').toggle();

            venueResults.recalculate();
        });
        $(window).resize(function () {
            autoHeightMobile();
        });
        autoHeightMobile();



    // functions

    function autoHeightMobile() {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        if (windowWidth < 768) {
            $('section.section').addClass('fp-auto-height');
        } else {
            $('section.section').removeClass('fp-auto-height');
        }
    }

    function getSliderCount() {
        var currentSlide;
        var slideCount;
        var total = $('.slide').length;
        var activeSlide = page.getActiveSlide();
        var index = activeSlide.index + 1;
        if (index && index < 10) {
            currentSlide = `0${index}`;
        } else {
            currentSlide = index;
        }
        if (total && total < 10) {
            slideCount = `0${total}`;
        } else {
            slideCount = total;
        }
        $('.slide-index').text(currentSlide);
        $('.slide-total').text(slideCount);
    }

    function getSquareFootageValue() {
        var squareFootageVal = squareFootageSlider.slider('getValue');
        if ((squareFootageVal[0] + 100) >= squareFootageVal[1]) {
        }
        $('.sf-low').text(squareFootageVal[0]);
        $('.sf-high').text(squareFootageVal[1]);
    }

    function getCapacityValue() {
        var capacityVal = capacitySlider.slider('getValue');
        if ((capacityVal[0] + 250) >= capacityVal[1]) {
        }
        $('.cap-low').text(capacityVal[0]);
        $('.cap-high').text(capacityVal[1]);
    }
});
```

Another thing you can do is add a namespace using iife (immediately invoked functions). You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

```
        let helper = (function ($) {
        let autoHeightMobile = function () {
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            if (windowWidth < 768) {
                $('section.section').addClass('fp-auto-height');
            } else {
                $('section.section').removeClass('fp-auto-height');
            }
        };

        let getSliderCount = function () {
            var currentSlide;
            var slideCount;
            var total = $('.slide').length;
            var activeSlide = page.getActiveSlide();
            var index = activeSlide.index + 1;
            if (index && index < 10) {
                currentSlide = `0${index}`;
            } else {
                currentSlide = index;
            }
            if (total && total < 10) {
                slideCount = `0${total}`;
            } else {
                slideCount = total;
            }
            $('.slide-index').text(currentSlide);
            $('.slide-total').text(slideCount);
        };

        let getSquareFootageValue = function () {
            var squareFootageVal = squareFootageSlider.slider('getValue');
            if ((squareFootageVal[0] + 100) >= squareFootageVal[1]) {
            }
            $('.sf-low').text(squareFootageVal[0]);
            $('.sf-high').text(squareFootageVal[1]);
        };

        let getCapacityValue = function () {
            var capacityVal = capacitySlider.slider('getValue');
            if ((capacityVal[0] + 250) >= capacityVal[1]) {
            }
            $('.cap-low').text(capacityVal[0]);
            $('.cap-high').text(capacityVal[1]);
        };
        return {
            autoHeightMobile,
            getSliderCount,
            getCapacityValue,
            getSquareFootageValue
        }
    })(jQuery)


    let app = (function ($) {

        let run = function () {
            var mobileMenuWrapper = $('div.mobile-menu-wrapper');
            var mobileMenuToggler = $('.mobile-nav-toggle');
            var mobileMailToggler = $('#mobileMailToggle');
            var currentPage = $('main').attr('id');
            var btnSlideLeft = $('.btn-slide-left');
            var btnScrollDown = $('.btn-page-scroll');
            var itemBox = $('.item-box');
            var btnSquare = $('.btn-square');
            var pageNavItem = $('.page-nav li');
            var serviceBtn = $('.service-box .icon-loader');
            var slideNum, serviceId;
            var page = new fullpage(`#${currentPage}`, {
                autoScrolling: true,
                continuousHorizontal: false,
                controlArrows: false,
                dragAndMove: false,
                fixedElements: '.topbar',
                loopHorizontal: false,
                responsiveSlides: false,
                scrollingSpeed: 500,
                touchSensitivity: 5,
                verticalCentered: false,
                normalScrollElements: '#intro, #services',
                onLeave: function (index, nextIndex, direction) {
                },

                onSlideLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction, nextSlideIndex) {
                },
                afterRender: function () {
                },
                afterResize: function () {
                },
                afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
                },
                afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
                    if (index === 2 && currentPage === 'venueDetail' || index === 2 && currentPage === 'experienceDetail') {
                        helper.getSliderCount();
                        $('.slide-counter').fadeIn();
                    }
                },
                afterResponsive: function (isResponsive) {
                }
            });
            var capacitySlider = $('#venueCapacity').slider({
                range: true,
                stop: 100,
                handle: 'custom',
            });
            var squareFootageSlider = $('#squareFootage').slider({
                range: true,
                step: 500,
                handle: 'custom',
            });
            // document ready

            $('.fade-in').show();
            $('.use-current-location').click(function () {
                $('.rep-results').fadeIn();
            });
            $('.toggle-experience').click(function () {
                $('.map-view').toggle();
                $('.grid-view').toggle();
            });

            $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
                html: true,
                content: function () {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    return $('#popover-content-' + id).html();
                },
                title: function () {
                    var title = $(this).attr('data-popover-content');
                    return $(title).children('.popover-heading').html();
                }
            });

            $(document).keyup(function (e) {
                if (e.key === 'Escape') {
                    $('.popover').removeClass('show');
                }
            });

            serviceBtn.click(function () {
                serviceId = $(this).prop('id');
                slideNum = serviceId.substr(serviceId.length - 1) - 1;
                console.log(slideNum);
                page.moveTo(2, slideNum);
            });

            btnSlideLeft.click(function () {
                page.moveSlideLeft();
                helper.getSliderCount();
            });
            var btnSlideRight = $('.btn-slide-right');
            btnSlideRight.click(function () {
                page.moveSlideRight();
                helper.getSliderCount();
            });

            $('#desktopMailToggle').click(function () {
                $('aside.sidebar').toggleClass('open');
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
            });

            mobileMenuToggler.click(function () {
                mobileMenuWrapper.toggleClass('menu-open');
                if (mobileMenuWrapper.hasClass('contact-form-showing')) {
                    mobileMenuWrapper.removeClass('contact-form-showing');
                    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
                }
            });

            mobileMailToggler.click(function () {
                mobileMenuWrapper.toggleClass('contact-form-showing');
                if (mobileMenuWrapper.hasClass('contact-form-showing')) {
                    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                } else {
                    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
                }
            });

            pageNavItem.click(function () {
                var section = $(this).index() + 1;
                page.moveTo(section);
            });

            btnScrollDown.click(function () {
                page.moveSectionDown();
            });

            btnSquare.click(function () {
                $('.btn-square').removeClass('loading');
                $(this).addClass('loading');
                $('.item-box').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).closest('.item-box').toggleClass('selected');
            });

            itemBox.click(function () {
                $('.item-box').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            });

            capacitySlider.on('slide', function () {
                helper.getCapacityValue();
            });

            squareFootageSlider.on('slide', function () {
                helper.getSquareFootageValue();
            });

            helper.getCapacityValue();
            helper.getSquareFootageValue();

            $('#resetFilters').click(function () {
                capacitySlider.slider('refresh');
                squareFootageSlider.slider('refresh');
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
                helper.getCapacityValue();
                helper.getSquareFootageValue();
            });

            $('.grid-map-toggle').click(function () {
                $('.map-view').toggle();
                $('.grid-view').toggle();

                venueResults.recalculate();
            });
            $(window).resize(function () {
                helper.autoHeightMobile();
            });
            helper.autoHeightMobile();

        };
        return {
            run
        }

    })(jQuery);



    $(function () {
        app.run();
    });
```

So there are two namespaces over here helper and app. helpers will hold all your functions which were in your functions block. And app will have all the document.ready stuff. Now your variables are not globally exposed they are only accessible in app.run method. Please make sure this script file should be included below the jQuery file or cdn link. Which will make sure $ is defined. As a standard practice always make sure all your JS (including jQuery) files should be included at end of body tag of html document.

Comment: Gracious thanks for your thoughtful answer. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @KirkRoss Welcome! Happy coding! 